# Sulu CMS: is it possible to restrict access to certain attributes of a specific template to certain roles?

Tags: sulu

We have a situation where we have two different roles of users: let's call them `content_labourer` and `content_boss`. There's a template we could call `very_cool_content`. On this template we've stated the following attributes:

- `title`: some string value
- `api_content_id`: an integer that accurately binds this content to some backend API content (we use this in our VeryCoolContentController to fire up some backend API stuff, obviously)
- `description`: a text value

I want my `content_boss` to be able to set the value for all these attributes. After all, he's the boss.

However, my `content_labourer` is not privy to the whole API business and would never in a million years know which value he should enter there, let alone that he should even be *able to* enter/change the value of `api_content_id`. He should also not be able to set the value of `title`, because that's none of his business.

Now my question is: how do I protect these particular attributes from being changed by (or in the ideal case: even be visible to) users without the `content_boss` role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but it is not possible to restrict access to single fields. But what you can do is to restrict the access to an entire page. Maybe you can make use of that instead, if you restructure your content somehow?

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) With "restructuring content", I assume you mean pulling apart the restricted/unrestricted elements and putting them into their own types and nodes? I fear that that would confuse some of our users. I'm also not a fan of having separate nodes because they also need (and have) separate routes, that then need restricting/redirecting in separate controller actions, etc.

Comment: The part with the own route is correct... What if you build the restricted part with snippets? And only allow a certain group to edit snippets?